# When using fig2plotly function to produce plotly charts, it failed when my MATLAB plot's axis is of datetime variable

Tags: matlab

When using fig2plotly function to produce plotly charts, it failed when my MATLAB plot's axis is of datetime variable. If I replace the axis with a numeric variable, it works fine. Any fixes for this bug?

Here are the errors:

Error using response_handler (line 31)
Hm... Plotly had some trouble decoding your 'args'. Are you sure your data or
styling object is in the right format? Check out the examples at
https://plotly.com/api for guidance.

Need help? Please try searching Plotly's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plotly'>Stack Overflow channel.

Error in makecall (line 32)
    response_handler(resp);

Error in plotly (line 28)
response = makecall(args, origin, structargs);

Error in plotlyfig/plotly (line 437)
                response = plotly(obj.data, args);

Error in fig2plotly (line 49)
p.plotly;

Error in creatplot4googlesites_usingploty (line 29)
resp = fig2plotly(fig);

Comment: Please create a [mre]